# CDN for a multitenant Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, amazon-cloudfront

I have created a multitenant Ruby on Rails application.
Each tenant will configure their domain name to my server's ip and then they can navigate to their site by just entering their domain.

Example
Abc.com will take you to the abc's web pages.
Xyz.com will take you ro the xyz's web pages.

Now I would like to know that how can I configure CDN for each tenant ?
I'm using cloudfront and there I see that I have to give the domain name.

And then cloudfront will track and cache the wen pages and other assets like js,css and images.
But what I'm not able to figure out is like how each tenant can take the advantage of CDN.

I mean't that the each domain example abc.something.com and xyz.something.com should make use of CSS CDN configured.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Comment: No I haven't got the solution yet.